Terraform apply errors out with a message: updating ECS Service InvalidParameterException: load balancers can have at most 5 items
I have an AWS ALB that is supposed to frontend an ECS Fargate frontend app written in Angular and a Backend that is written in NestJS. I intend to use a Single ALB for both frontend and backend and therefore, I have setup a listener rule that should take about 7 backend condition rules which are path patterns.
The error I get when I try to deploy this app is:-
updating ECS Service InvalidParameterException: load balancers can have at most 5 items.
I know the limit is about 100 items from the AWS documentation.
I have this Terraform code that is supposed to provision the infrastructure:-
resource "aws_ecs_service" "ecs_service_def" {
  name            = "backend-service"
  task_definition = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.ecs_task_def.family}"
  desired_count   = 1
  force_new_deployment = true
  health_check_grace_period_seconds  = 300
  launch_type     = "FARGATE"
  cluster         = data.aws_ecs_cluster.this.id
  depends_on      = [
    aws_iam_role_policy.ecs_service_role_policy,
    data.aws_alb_listener.selected443
  ]
  deployment_circuit_breaker {
    enable = true
    rollback = true
  }
  network_configuration {
    security_groups = ["sg-0233333337779"]
    subnets         = var.db_subnet_ids
  }

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.upload.arn
    container_name   = "backend"
    container_port   = "3000"
  }

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.search-logs.arn
    container_name   = "backend"
    container_port   = "3000"
  }

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.log-file-info.arn
    container_name   = "backend"
    container_port   = "3000"
  }


  dynamic "load_balancer" {
    for_each = local.ecs_load_balancers
    content {
      container_name   = load_balancer.value.container_name
      container_port   = load_balancer.value.container_port
      target_group_arn = load_balancer.value.target_group_arn
    }
  }   
}

locals {
  ecs_load_balancers = [
  {
    container_name   = "backend"
    container_port   = "3000"
    target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.download.arn
  },
  {
    container_name   = "backend"
    container_port   = "3000"
    target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.update-log-status.arn
  },
  {
    container_name   = "backend"
    container_port   = "3000"
    target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.log-upload-info.arn
  },
  {
    container_name   = "backend"
    container_port   = "3000"
    target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.recent-logs.arn
  }]
}

I am using dynamic block to provision the remaining rules but no matter whatever change I make to the Terraform logic, the "apply" action always errors out with the given message.

I have pasted the screenshot of my ALB and there are about 9 listener rules which I can extend to 100.
here is the documentation link:-
https://docs.aws.amazon.com//elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-limits.html
another thread where this was discussed:-
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/25306
Appreciate if anyone can share a solution to this issue.

"I know the limit is about 100 items from the AWS documentation." If you are going to quote the documentation, provide a link to that documentation in your question. The documentation actually states the limit for loadBalancers in the ECS service definition is 5, not "about 100": https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/register-multiple-targetgroups.html

From Registering multiple target groups with an Amazon ECS service:

For services that use an Application Load Balancer or Network Load Balancer, you cannot attach more than five target groups to a service.


My Terraform code suffices both the conditions:-
Specifying multiple target groups in a service definition is only supported under the following conditions:
The service must use either an Application Load Balancer or Network Load Balancer.
The service must use the rolling update (ECS) deployment controller type.
from the AWS documentation link that you shared!

@Biplab as mentioned in both the documentation and error message, in order to solve your problem you need to use maximum 5 target groups.
